# Iterating over a list of lambda functions in python, given the same parameter

Tags: python, lambda, functional-programming

I want to make a lambda function of x such that takes the maximum between the results of all lambda functions in a list for that given x.

Any ideas on how to make this functional for any size of list?

```
a = lambda(x): someprocess0(x)
b = lambda(x): someprocess1(x)
c = lambda(x): someprocess2(x)

funcList = [a, b, c]

function = lambda(x): max(funcList[0](x), funcList[1](x), funcList[2](x))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) to apply `x` to each function:

```
function = lambda x: max(f(x) for f in funcList)
```

This avoids keeping all function results in memory in a list, when you only need to track the highest value found so far.

You might be interested in the [Python *Functional Programming HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html) included in the Python documentation, which teaches about generator expressions and other functional techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following function:

```
def computeResults(functions, value):
    res = []
    for f in functions:
        res.append(f(value))
    return res

function = lambda x: max(computeResults(funcList, x))
```